# How to get the top 10 values in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I have simple question:

I have a **`postgresql`** table: `Scores(score integer)`.

How would I get the highest 10 scores the fastest?

**UPDATE:**

I will be doing this query multiple times and am aiming for the fastest solution.

Answer (score 681):

For this you can use [limit](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html)

```
select *
from scores
order by score desc
limit 10
```

If performance is important (when is it not ;-) look for an index on score.

---

Starting with version 8.4, you can also use the standard ([SQL:2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause)) [`fetch first`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT)

```
select *
from scores
order by score desc
fetch first 10 rows only
```

---

As @Raphvanns pointed out, this will give you the `first 10 rows` literally. To remove duplicate values, you have to select [`distinct`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) rows, e.g.

```
select distinct *
from scores
order by score desc
fetch first 10 rows only
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f2976/2/0)

Comment: `fetch first X rows only` is the answer I was looking for -- thank you from the far future!

Answer (score 43):

Seems you are looking for `ORDER BY` in `DESC`ending order with [LIMIT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html) clause:

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
  scores
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Of course `SELECT *` could seriously affect performance, so use it with caution.

Answer (score 15):

Note that if there are ties in top 10 values, you will only get the top 10 rows, not the top 10 *values* with the answers provided.
Ex: if the top 5 values are 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 but your data contains
10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 you will only get 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 as your top 5 with a `LIMIT`

Here is a solution which will return more than 10 rows if there are ties but you will get all the rows where `some_value_column` is technically in the top 10.

```
select
  *
from
  (select
     *,
     rank() over (order by some_value_column desc) as my_rank
  from mytable) subquery
where my_rank <= 10
```

Comment: From his question there is only one column in the table.  So why not "select distinct score from Scores order by score desc limit 10"?

Comment: @Derek, good point. Though that would probably not be the case in a real world app where we are usually looking to identify the top N of "somethings".

Comment: True.  Just focusing on his exact question.  Also, I've had good luck using limit in a subquery like yours, e.g. "select * from table where value in (select distinct value from table order by value desc limit 10)"  I _think_ that's equivalent to yours.  I'm not sure which of our queries would perform better, it would probably depend on the table structure and indexing.

Comment: There is a missing keyword OVER after rank()

Answer (score 4):

```
(SELECT <some columns>
FROM mytable
<maybe some joins here>
WHERE <various conditions>
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10)

UNION ALL

(SELECT <some columns>
FROM mytable
<maybe some joins here>
WHERE <various conditions>
ORDER BY date ASC    
LIMIT 10)
```