# Postgresql: Create View from 2 Tables, JOIN on the max values of same column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables

Sys_Log

```
request_id   request_date
----------------------------
1            2022-01-01
2            2022-01-02
```

Values

```
request_id   city      country
---------------------------------
1            Berlin    DE
1            Dortmund  DE
1            Dresden   DE
1            Paris     FR
1            London    EN
2            Dublin    IR
2            Bochum    DE
2            Essen     DE
2            Herne     DE
```

I am trying to create a view where only the data from the last request (max request_id) will be displayed.

Ideal result

```
request_id   city      country    request_date
----------------------------------------------
2            Dublin    IR         2022-01-02
2            Bochum    DE         2022-01-02
2            Essen     DE         2022-01-02
2            Herne     DE         2022-01-02
```

So far I made one where request id is matched in both tables

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT city, 
    country, 
    sys_log.request_id,
    sys_log.request_date
FROM public."Values" AS VAL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sys.request_date, 
    sys.request_id
    FROM public."Sys_Log" AS sys
) AS sys_log ON sys_log.request_id = VAL.request_id
WHERE VAL.request_id IS NOT NULL) AS VAL_View
```

I am not sure how to proceed, with max(request_id) I am getting an error.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT city, 
    country, 
    sys_log.request_id,
    sys_log.request_date
FROM public."Values" AS VAL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sys.request_date, 
    max(sys.request_id) as max_ri
    FROM public."Sys_Log" AS sys
) AS sys_log ON sys_log.max_ri= VAL.request_id
WHERE VAL.request_id IS NOT NULL) AS VAL_View
```

Error:

Spalte »sys.request_date« muss in der GROUP-BY-Klausel erscheinen oder in einer Aggregatfunktion verwendet werden

Like the sys.request_date has to be used in GROUP-BY or in an agg. function.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674031/how-to-get-the-top-10-values-in-postgresql) you can use `limit`. So your query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT city, 
    country, 
    sys_log.request_id,
    sys_log.request_date
FROM public."Values" AS VAL
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sys.request_date, 
    sys.request_id
    FROM public."Sys_Log" ORDER BY sys.request_id DESC LIMIT 1 AS sys
) AS sys_log ON sys_log.request_id = VAL.request_id
WHERE VAL.request_id IS NOT NULL) AS VAL_View
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RANK](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tutorial-window.html) function  , try :

```
with cte as (
      SELECT request_id,city,country
             ,RANK () OVER (ORDER BY request_id desc ) id_rank
     FROM
     values_tbl
) select cte.request_id,city,country,request_date 
  from cte 
  inner join sys_Log on cte.request_id=sys_Log.request_id
  where cte.id_rank=1;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> request_id    city    country request_date
>      2        Herne      DE   2022-01-02
>      2        Essen      DE   2022-01-02
>      2        Bochum     DE   2022-01-02
>      2        Dublin     IR   2022-01-02
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e3c3b6612abb10fbae58ab044195b126)

View query:

```
create view my_view as with cte as (
      SELECT request_id,city,country
             ,RANK () OVER (ORDER BY request_id desc ) id_rank
     FROM
     values_tbl
) select cte.request_id,city,country,request_date 
  from cte 
  inner join sys_Log on cte.request_id=sys_Log.request_id
  where cte.id_rank=1;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0db799815466784355569999a6f42ed2)