# I want to select 2 data from database which durations less than 150

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with my SQL command. I want to select 2 movies which 2 movies sum of durations less than 150 I wrote this SQL command:

```
Select
   movie_title,Sum(movie_time) as sum_movie
From
  movie_movie
Group By
  movie_title
Having 
  Sum(movie_time)<100
Order By
  sum_movie DESC
```

Comment: What does your query do wrongly other than the typo of using 100 instead of 150?

Comment: For the limit of 2 rows you may want: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674031/how-to-get-the-top-10-values-in-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674031/how-to-get-the-top-10-values-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

You can get two movies with minimum movie_time values ​​with `order by movie_time ASC limit 2` in CTE, and then use that in the condition.

```
with  two_min_movie as (
  select * 
  from movie_movie 
  order by movie_time ASC limit 2
)
select * 
from two_min_movie 
where (select sum(movie_time) from two_min_movie) < 150
```

Demo in [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a9ce26c85fab8f084cf929e7e6405a16)