# How to get the top 99% values in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

Seemingly similar to [How to get the top 10 values in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674031/how-to-get-the-top-10-values-in-postgresql), yet somehow very different.

We'll set it up similar to that question:

I have a postgresql table: `Scores(score integer)`.

How would I get the highest 99% of the scores?  We cannot say that we know beforehand how many rows there are, so we can't use the same limit to an integer trick.  SQL Server has an easy `SELECT TOP` syntax -- is there anything similarly simple in the postgresql world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be doable with [`percent_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#id-1.5.8.28.6.2.2.3.1.1.1)

```
select score
from (
  select score, percent_rank() over (order by score desc) as pct_rank
  from scores
) t
where pct_rank <= 0.99
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [ntile](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function to partition the rows into percentiles and then select the rows where tile > 99

example:

```sql
-- following query generates 1000 rows with random 
-- scores and selects the 99th percentile using the ntile function.
-- because the chance of the same random value appearing twice is extremely
-- small, the result should in most cases yield 10 rows.
with scores as (
  select
    id
  , random() score
  from generate_series(1, 1000) id
 )
, percentiles AS (
  select 
    *
  , ntile(100) over (order by score) tile
  from scores
)
select 
  id
, score
from percentiles 
where tile > 99
```